não consigo instalar o Npm e nem usar o node, mesmo baixando o chocolatey e tudo pedido pelo instalador do node
npm : O arquivo C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1 não pode ser carregado porque a execução de scripts foi desabilitada neste sistema.
Para obter mais informações, consulte about_Execution_Policies em https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
No linha:1 caractere:1

npm config get prefix

  + CategoryInfo          : ErrodeSegurança: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess




No link indicado pelo proprio powershell, para a documentação da Microsoft, tem as orientações de como habilitar scripts em execução no powershell. Você também pode baixar o .msi no site oficial do nodejs ou usar o CMD ao invés do powershell.
